# Run a scheduled task when a disk volume is attached

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I have this Windows 10 virtual environment where frequently I need to attach raw disk volumes to the virtual machine, then I need to run `diskpart` on it to initialize it. I think I need Window Task Scheduler to do the job. So here are the steps:

1. The volume is attached by the VM managing tool.
2. The scheduled task founds that the volume is attached, then run the diskpart script.

The `diskpart` part is easy, but how do I know if a volume is attached? I think it involves in using system events as task triggers, but what events should I look into?

**Diskpart Logic**

```
select disk 1
attribute disk clear readonly
online disk
convert mbr
create part primary
format quick
assign letter d:
exit
```

Comment: What `diskpart` commands are you using exactly to mount, etc?

Comment: @JUICED_IT Something like this: https://gist.github.com/gastlygem/f78cb5422ebfaf46934d2e1aa8350c63

Comment: Diskpart doesn't sound like a very safe tool to automate. Maybe you should just run it as a script using diskpart's `/s` flag. ([Docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614984(v=ws.11).aspx))

Comment: @MosheKatz That's what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1):

> **The `diskpart` part is easy, but how do I know if a volume is
>   attached?**
>
> *Your DiskPart Logic*
>
> ```
> select disk 1
> attribute disk clear readonly
> online disk
> convert mbr
> create part primary
> format quick
> assign letter d:
> exit
> ```

---

You can easily confirm if a volume exist or not by using the batch script logic as (simple `ECHO` command examples below):

- `IF EXIST D:\ ECHO SUCCESS`, or
- `IF NOT EXIST D:\ ECHO UNSUCCESSFUL`.

Based on your need, adjust your logic accordingly afterwards by either confirming this "D" drive disk partition exists or not since you assign it the "D" drive letter via diskpart.

***General Examples:***

1. `IF [NOT] EXIST D:\ <SOME LOGIC BASED ON IF LOGIC RESULT>`

> **So it has to detect it first, then execute diskpart**

*Script below to check every 30 seconds for the "D" drive and only run the logic then end once it's found.*

```
@ECHO ON

:Exist_Or_Not
PING -n 30 127.0.0.1 > nil
IF NOT EXIST D:\ GOTO :Exist_Or_Not
IF EXIST D:\ GOTO :Your_DiskPart_Logic

:Your_DiskPart_Logic
select disk 1
attribute disk clear readonly
online disk
convert mbr
create part primary
format quick
assign letter d:
exit
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**IF Condition**](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't making it clear. I need to detect the volume first, then execute diskpart...

Comment: @WangDingwei Okay, what I have above should STILL work then i.e. use either IF or IF NOT and then based on those results, DO SOMETHING. In other words you'd run `IF NOT EXIST "D:\" <THEN DO SOMETHING WHEN THIS IS THE CASE TO MAKE IF RIGHT THEN>` otherwise run `IF EXIST "D:\" <THEN I'M HAPPY SO DO THE HAPPY LOGIC>`. You're not asking for rocket science here so either decide, do I need to know if it's there or not there, and then based on MY LOGIC of this process, DO SOMETHING... It's clear sir and this will work or else tell me everything to make it clearer that you're not disclosing.

Comment: @WangDingwei Depending on your specific needs, use the IF or IF NOT conditional logic accordingly for your needs. It shouldn't matter if you run logic using it before or after you run the diskpart commands; you should be able to get this to work with everything you explained and your comment on this answer.

Comment: Your logic works only provided that the volume is already attached, but in my case, the guest OS doesn't know when exactly the volume will be attached. So it has to detect it first, then execute diskpart.

Comment: @WangDingwei I just added the logic above towards the bottom of my answer to take care of that issue. Sorry for the delayed response, just noticed the comment above; not sure how I missed it.